# Exception when comparing dates - Npgsql.PostgresException: '42883'

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, linq

I'm trying to get records with a date that are the same or later than a given date. But this Exception keeps happening:

> Npgsql.PostgresException: '42883: operator does not exist: character varying >= timestamp without time zone'

And here is my code:

```
var bairro = "test";
var dataBusca = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

var buscaImovel = _context.ImovelModel
         .Where(context => context.bairronome == bairro &&
         context.datageracaoarq >= DateTime.Parse(dataBusca)).ToList(); //exception happens here
```

The dates in my database are using the "yyyy-MM-dd" timestamp. What could be the problem?

Comment: The error is pretty specific: `operator does not exist:character varying >= timestamp without time zone'`.  So I'm going to say the field in the database is of `varchar` not `timestamp`. If so not a good idea to keep timestamps in a character field. Your choices: 1) Change to `timestamp` type  2) Cast the varchar to `timestamp` in the query.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver yes, the field in the database is varchar. But if I try to convert it in the query this happens: "System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression ...  could not be translated." so I thought the query was correct and the problem could be something else..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ could not translate the expression if I casted the field to DateTime in it. The solution was changing the field type in the database to 'date'.